# ASP.Net Core Npgsql An operation is already in progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, npgsql

In order to reuse the same DbCommand and not instatiating a new connection every time I need to access the DB in the same request, I created a method that saves the DbCommand and returns it if it was previously instantiated:

```
public static class InformacionInscripcionesViewModel {

        private static NpgsqlConnection _dbConnection;
        private static NpgsqlCommand _dbCommand;

        private static NpgsqlCommand GetDbCommand() {
            InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbConnection = InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbConnection ?? new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.1.127;Username=siu;Password=123456;Database=guaraniprueba20160816");
            if (InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbConnection.Open();

            return InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbCommand
                   ?? (InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbCommand = new NpgsqlCommand {Connection = InformacionInscripcionesViewModel._dbConnection});
        }
}
```

Example of how it is used in a Model:

```
var dbCommand = InformacionInscripcionesViewModel.GetDbCommand();
dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT sga_propuestas.nombre_abreviado AS nombre_carrera, ....";
dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I make 2 simultaneous requests to a URL using it, it throws an exception at `dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` with message `An operation is already in progress`.

What could I do to prevent this? Should `DbCommand` be instanted every time prior to use? Any light on this?

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress.
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SIUNPAZ.Models.InformacionInscripcionesViewModels.InformacionInscripcionesViewModel.GetTotalesInscripcionesPorMaterias(DateTime fechaDesde, DateTime fechaHasta, String carrera)
   at SIUNPAZ.Controllers.InformacionInscripcionesController.PorMaterias(DateTime fechaDesde, DateTime fechaHasta, String carrera)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … and not instatiating a new connection every time I need to access the DB in the same request

Like most other ADO.NET implementations, Npgsql has connection pooling, so as long as you `Dispose()` the connection object the underlying connection will be reused unless there is a simultaneous query. Don't fix the bug in your ad-hoc connection pooling, just use that given to you already.

Comment: So, should I dispose the NpgsqlConnection or the NpgsqlCommand?

Comment: Definitely dispose the connection. While you could unset the connection property of the command and then set it again after wards, you aren't saving much in doing that (the command on its own is "light") so really I'd just put the two in `using` blocks and have them disposed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't share DB connections across requests which is essentially what you're doing by making them static.  It's ok to share a single connection for multiple commands in a single request, but its lifetime should be tied to the lifetime of the request.  As a start you can remove the 'static'  and your code should run.  You may want to look at an IoC container (Unity, Ninject, StructureMap, etc.) to create the connections for you and just ask for them in your constructor.  Most have lifetime managers that can automatically scope the object to the HTTP request.

Also it is generally considered to be bad practice to have logic in your ViewModels.  ViewModels shouldn't have DbConnections.  You should look into either making services for data access or moving the DB code to a controller.